# code to Voice commands with Send Keys In C#

Tags: c#, voice-recognition, sendkeys

Ok so i have a program that im trying to build where i speak a command and it simulates the keyboard press. I have Used This Set Up

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;

case "Close window":
    SendKeys.Send("%{F4}");
    break;
```

That one works and the active window will close when i say "Close window" ...(case refers to a text doc that has the typed out commands)

Then I tried to use the program while a game was playing i was trying to use a command "One" to simulate the 1 key being pressed.

```
case "One":
    SendKeys.Send("{1}");
    break;
```

But this did something weird it made the options window open so i tried many different keys and they all made the options window open rather then the items they were supposed to 
anyone have any ideas. the goal is to help my little brother who is disabled he wants to play a game that requires more keyboard imput then he can do so i want to allow him to use his voice to control some of it

any help would be great thanks

Comment: What key on the keyboard would you press to open the options window?  Maybe there is some link there...

Comment: The key for options is F11. whats weird is i can clearly say the command like the word One and options opens Or Inventory for the I key and options opens just don't get it

Comment: Why are you enclosing 1 in braces? I can see a function key in conjunction with a modifier needing it but I don't think a simple key like 1 needs that.

Comment: well that's what i came up with on research of Sendkeys but i have tried it with out and still it acts like it will work but it doesn't. I guess the question is will sendkeys work with a game, according to my research it simulates a keypress to the active application. but it is not acting like i pressed the key is there a better solution i should use?